# Solve:Value was either too large or too small for an Int32

Tags: asp.net, query-string, int32

I am passing query string and the url is as follows-> http://localhost:1086/Web/EditMobile.aspx?sno=2. 
But when i try to enter the url as follows,localhost:1086/Web/EditMobile.aspx?sno=2**3424324423432424** , i get the following error->Value was either too large or too small for an Int32. How do i handle this error. I must get an error report like " the value is not found in the table or database"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're presumably using something like `int.Parse`. Instead, use `int.TryParse`, and if it returns `false`, render the error message you actually want.

Comment: @ David: Yes David indeed I am using int.Parse. Let me trying out.

Comment: Yes David indeed I am using int.Parse. Let me try it out.

Comment: You'll need to declare the `int` variable first, and pass it as an `out` parameter to the `TryParse` method.

Answer (score 0):

Because Int32 only support 10 digit value `0123456789`, when we are trying more than 10 digit line string convert or initialize like `01234566789123456798`

```
 int stratNo = Convert.ToInt31(Console.ReadLine()); \\less then 10 digit


 double stratNo = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); \\ more than 10 digit
```